# What's the difference between Ruby's puts and write methods?

Tags: ruby

What's the difference between...

```
File.open('abc', 'w') { |f| f.puts 'abcde' }
```

...and...

```
File.open('abc', 'w') { |f| f.write 'abcde' }
```

...?

Comment: @RichB (aka "The OCD editing guy") The original lowercase "and" was technically more correct.  It's a conjunction, not the start of a new sentence.

Comment: @MarkusQ: Rich B is just an automated trolling bot.  Clearly his grammar system needs to be upgraded.

Comment: @MarkusQ: I disagree. Edit it if you feel differently.

Comment: See here: http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/capital.asp

Comment: @JonB: Mind pointing out which rule you think justifies this?

Comment: Let's just change the word "and" into "&".  Problem solved!

Comment: @Rich: Rule 16. Although they don't say anything about lines of code, I would say one line of code == one sentence.

Comment: Fixed. And I do not agree at all with your interpretation of grammar.

Comment: @Rich - that was actually less clear. Rollback'd.

Comment: @Jon B: Ok, be childish and roll back, good idea.

Comment: A wise man once said "Edit if you feel differently".

Comment: @Daniel: And how does that relate to it being a completely new line?

Comment: @JonB: Whatever, I was hoping for a good compromise, since we cannot agree on the grammar involved, but rolling back shows me where you are at on this one.

Comment: @Jon: This brings up the troubling question of how our grammatical structures work with blocks of code in them.  Somebody call Strunk & White!  What's that?  They're DEAD?!  Well, we're screwed...

Comment: @JonB: It's "roll'd back" not "rollback'd".  Your lack of grammar skills is apparent.

Comment: You guys are tragic.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

puts appends a newline, write does not.  Technically, puts appends the record separator (which is usually a newline) to the output if it doesn't have one at the end.  write outputs only what it is given.

Answer (score 13):

In cases like this, I always start with the Ruby Core documentation, in this case the [IO](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html) class.

```
ios.puts(obj, ...) => nil
```

> Writes the given objects to ios as with `IO#print`. Writes a record separator (typically a newline) after any that do not already end with a newline sequence. If called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line. If called without arguments, outputs a single record separator.

```
ios.write(string) => integer
```

> Writes the given string to ios. The stream must be opened for writing. If the argument is not a string, it will be converted to a string using `to_s`. Returns the number of bytes written.