# What is the difference between print and puts?

Tags: ruby

For example in this line of code I wrote, `print` and `puts` produce different results.

```
1.upto(1000).each { |i| print i if i % 2 == 0 }
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612258/whats-the-difference-between-rubys-puts-and-write-methods, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255324/p-vs-puts-in-ruby, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415834/print-function-in-ruby

Answer (score 402, accepted):

`puts` adds a new line to the end of each argument if there is not one already.

`print` does not add a new line.

---

**For example:**

`puts [[1,2,3], [4,5,nil]]` Would return:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Whereas `print [[1,2,3], [4,5,nil]]`
would return:

```
[[1,2,3], [4,5,nil]]
```

> *Notice how puts does not output the nil value whereas print does.*

Comment: Actually, a newline after each argument. That's a key point and not clear from the Ruby docs (since the example has only 1 argument).

Comment: There is another thing ... extend the array class and override the to_s method. puts doesn't use the new to_s for an object of your new class while print does

Comment: using irb 0.9.5 puts("a") and puts("a\n") have exactly the same output on the REPL.

Comment: @kapv89 That's not true: I've just tried and both puts e print use the to_s method. Only p doesn't use it.

Comment: @cdunn2001 `puts "howdy" "partner"` gets me `howdypartner` in one line. no linefeeds after each argument...

Comment: @Fronker, that's still just one argument. The compiler concatenates adjacent strings.

Comment: You say they "return" those outputs but they really just *print* them. What they "return" is `nil`.

Comment: Also, apparently `print` without arguments assumes $_ while `puts` doesn't, at least from my testing.

Answer (score 62):

A big difference is if you are displaying arrays.
Especially ones with NIL.
For example:

```
print [nil, 1, 2]
```

gives

```
[nil, 1, 2]
```

but

```
puts [nil, 1, 2]
```

gives

```
1
2
```

Note, no appearing nil item (just a blank line) and each item on a different line.

Comment: I noticed this today, which brought me here. I'd love to know the thinking on that. It seems like a special case for puts to handle arrays like that. Wondering what the rationale was... Is it just to be analogous to other languages?

Comment: It makes sense since puts will output with a new line, so you can think of it as iterating on the array and calling puts on each line... it is odd, however, that it doesn't output `nil`

Answer (score 42):

`print` outputs each argument, followed by `$,`, to `$stdout`, followed by `$\`. It is equivalent to `args.join($,) + $\`

`puts` sets both `$,` and `$\` to "\n" and then does the same thing as `print`. The key difference being that *each argument* is a new line with `puts`.

You can `require 'english'` to access those global variables with [user-friendly names](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/English/rdoc/English.html).

Comment: nice tip on the `english` lib

Answer (score 17):

[The API docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-puts) give some good hints:

> ### `print() → nil`
>
> ### `print(obj, ...) → nil`
>
> Writes the given object(s) to *ios*. Returns `nil`.
>
> The stream must be opened for writing. Each given object that isn't a
>   string will be converted by calling its `to_s` method. When
>   called without arguments, prints the contents of `$_`.
>
> If the output field separator (`$,`) is not `nil`, it
>   is inserted between objects. If the output record separator
>   (`$\`) is not `nil`, it is appended to the output.
>
> ...
>
> ### `puts(obj, ...) → nil`
>
> Writes the given object(s) to *ios*. Writes a newline after any that
>   do not already end with a newline sequence. Returns `nil`.
>
> The stream must be opened for writing. If called with an array argument,
>   writes each element on a new line. Each given object that isn't a
>   string or array will be converted by calling its `to_s` method.
>   If called without arguments, outputs a single newline.

Experimenting a little with the points given above, the differences seem to be:

- Called with multiple arguments, `print` separates them by the 'output field separator' `$,` (which defaults to nothing) while `puts` separates them by newlines. `puts` also puts a newline after the final argument, while `print` does not.

  ```
  2.1.3 :001 > print 'hello', 'world'
  helloworld => nil 
  2.1.3 :002 > puts 'hello', 'world'
  hello
  world
   => nil
  2.1.3 :003 > $, = 'fanodd'
   => "fanodd" 
  2.1.3 :004 > print 'hello', 'world'
  hellofanoddworld => nil 
  2.1.3 :005 > puts 'hello', 'world'
  hello
  world
   => nil
  ```
- `puts` automatically unpacks arrays, while `print` does not:

  ```
  2.1.3 :001 > print [1, [2, 3]], [4]
  [1, [2, 3]][4] => nil 
  2.1.3 :002 > puts [1, [2, 3]], [4]
  1
  2
  3
  4
   => nil
  ```
- `print` with no arguments prints `$_` (the last thing read by [`gets`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/IO.html#method-i-gets)), while `puts` prints a newline:

  ```
  2.1.3 :001 > gets
  hello world
   => "hello world\n" 
  2.1.3 :002 > puts

   => nil 
  2.1.3 :003 > print
  hello world
   => nil
  ```
- `print` writes the output record separator `$\` after whatever it prints, while `puts` ignores this variable:

  ```
  mark@lunchbox:~$ irb
  2.1.3 :001 > $\ = 'MOOOOOOO!'
   => "MOOOOOOO!" 
  2.1.3 :002 > puts "Oink! Baa! Cluck! "
  Oink! Baa! Cluck! 
   => nil 
  2.1.3 :003 > print "Oink! Baa! Cluck! "
  Oink! Baa! Cluck! MOOOOOOO! => nil
  ```

Answer (score 4):

`puts` call the `to_s` of each argument and adds a new line to each string, if it does not end with new line.
`print` just output each argument by calling their `to_s`.

for example:
`puts "one two"`: 
`one two`

{new line}

`puts "one two\n"`:
`one two`

{new line} #puts will not add a new line to the result, since the string ends with a new line

`print "one two"`:
`one two`

`print "one two\n"`:
`one two`

{new line}

And there is another way to output: `p`

> For each object, directly writes obj.inspect followed by a newline to the program’s standard output.

It is helpful to output debugging message.
`p "aa\n\t"`: `aa\n\t`

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to output array within string using `puts`, you will get the same result as if you were using `print`:

```
puts "#{[0, 1, nil]}":
[0, 1, nil]
```

But if not withing a quoted string then yes. The only difference is between new line when we use `puts`.

Comment: -1 for two reasons. Firstly, a lack of clarity: I don't understand what the initial "But..." here intends for this to follow on from, nor do I understand what the "yes" in the final paragraph is replying to. Secondly, for a lack of correctness: you say that using `printf` instead of `puts` in your example code will give the same result, but in fact it doesn't. The `puts` variant adds a newline at the end while the `printf` one doesn't, just like the case where there's no array interpolated into the string. (Necessarily so, since the interpolation happens when evaluating the string literal.)

Comment: Aha! After reading other answers, I think I understand - you intended this to be a reply to https://stackoverflow.com/a/14534145/1709587? In any case, it doesn't really stand a an answer on its own.