# What is the differences between print and puts in Ruby with example?

Tags: ruby

May be this is a duplicate question, What is the differences between print and puts in Ruby? Can I have answer with example please?

Comment: Why don't you try by yourself ?

Comment: please read - beginning ruby from novice to professional, I took that example for you

Comment: This is most definitely a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018633/what-is-the-difference-between-print-and-puts?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
irb(main):014:0> class Person
irb(main):015:1>  attr_accessor :name, :age, :gender
irb(main):016:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):017:0> person = Person.new
=> #<Person:0x2bf03e0>
irb(main):018:0> person.name = "Robert"
=> "Robert"
irb(main):019:0> person.age = 52
=> 52
irb(main):020:0> person.gender = "male"
=> "male"

irb(main):021:0> puts person
#<Person:0x2bf03e0>
=> nil
irb(main):022:0> print person
#<Person:0x2bf03e0>=> nil
irb(main):023:0> print person.name
Robert=> nil
irb(main):024:0> puts person.name
Robert
=> nil
```

The difference between print and puts is that puts automatically moves the output cursor to the next line (that is, it adds a newline character to start a new line  unless the string already ends with a newline), whereas print continues printing text onto the same line as the previous time.

puts isn't prefixed by the name of a class or object upon which to complete the method and puts is a method made available from the Kernel module and that is included and searched by default, so usually you won’t need to use Kernel.puts to refer to it.

```
Kernel.puts "Hello, world!"
```

puts takes only one argument and is rarely followed by other methods or logic, so parentheses are not strictly necessary.

Comment: `puts` adds a newline character to start a new line unless the string already ends with a newline.

Answer (score 2):

`print` does not add a newline at the end.. `puts` does.

Most other languages have similar structures too.

Java has `System.out.println()` and `System.out.print()`

C# has `Console.WriteLine()` and `Console.Write()`

Pascal had `Writeln()` and `Write()`

Answer (score 2):

It's simple. `puts` automatically appends a newline when it prints. `print` prints the string without modification.

Another difference is in the number of underlying write operations. `puts` is (roughly) equivalent to:

```
STDOUT.write(str)
STDOUT.write("\n")
```

And `print` (roughly) equivalent to:

```
STDOUT.write(str)
```

So, in multithreaded environments, `puts` can create some weird looking stuff, like this:

```
Message1Messa
ge2
(blank line)
```

While `print`ing a string with a concatenated newline yields:

```
Message1
Message2
```

Other than that, they're the same.

Answer (score 1):

There are two major differences between puts and print in general.

**1. New line**

`puts` take every element and prints in a newline(without specifying the need of a new line character `"\n"` in the end)

Whereas print doesn't print each element in a new line unless the programmer explicitly specify it.

```
puts "Hello, Welcome to Ruby"
```

**Output:**

```
 Hello, Welcome to Ruby
 Dell-System-XPS:~/Documents/2016RoR/Ruby$



print "Hello, Welcome to Ruby"
```

**Output:**

```
 Hello, Welcome to RubyDell-System-XPS:~/Documents/2016RoR/Ruby$
```

Did you notice, there is no new line after the output.
However, the new line should work when you explicitly mention the new line character like below

```
print "Hello, Welcome to Ruby \n"
```

**Output:**

```
Hello, Welcome to Ruby
Dell-System-XPS:~/Documents/2016RoR/Ruby$
```

**2. Empty characters or NIL values**

`print` statement prints the empty or NIL values but puts statement doesn't print them if they contain `NIL` values in it.

```
> print [nil, 33,44,55]
> [nil, 33, 44, 55] => nil 


 > puts [nil, 33,44,55]
 >  33
 >  44
 >  55
 => nil
```

"You see the difference, there is no NIL value printed  while using `puts`"

Answer (score 0):

A comparison can be see in [print vs put](http://mattberther.com/2009/02/11/puts-vs-print-in-ruby). For example take a look on [Input & output in Ruby](http://zetcode.com/lang/rubytutorial/io/).