# Response of a web request on terminal when ruby script is run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I am testing with Stripe for my website.This is the script to create an account.

```
 require 'stripe'
 Stripe.api_key =  'sk_test_viztoDNoflBnvkVwr8QG9SPE'
 Stripe::Account.create(
  :country => "US",
  :managed => false,
  :email => "ra@stripe.com"
)
```

The ruby code is  run in the terminal with the command

```
ruby stripe.rb
```

The command runs successfully . But I am not recieving the json response in the terminal. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: You will need to print the result to the console, try setting your create command to a variable and `puts` it to the console

Comment: Have you tried using `puts`?

Comment: Well that was a stupid question. I should have tried `puts`. It worked.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but even if it's only a test key, you should not share secret API keys. I recommend you edit your message to replace your key with e.g. `"sk_test_..."` and roll out a new API key. (You can do so from your [dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys) by clicking on the recycle icon next to each key).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a command in the ruby console (irb) the console will always repeats back the return value of a command.

Ruby does not do that when you run a file with the ruby command. Instead your need to use [puts or print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018633/what-is-the-difference-between-print-and-puts) to write to [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29).

```
require 'stripe'

Stripe.api_key =  'sk_test_viztoDNoflBnvkVwr8QG9SPE'
response = Stripe::Account.create(
  :country => "US",
  :managed => false,
  :email => "ra@stripe.com"
)
puts response
```