# issue with ruby split

Tags: arrays, ruby

my objective is to read a txt.file, and split the contents into an array. However I am having issue with the split command.

My text file content is this

> Acosta,1,3,0,0,0
>     Amezcua,2,1,2,0,2
>     Avalos,0,1,1,0,0

My code is this

```
file = open("score2.txt", "r")

file.each do |line|
  array = line.split(",")
  print array
end
```

However my powershell returns this

```
["Acosta", "1", "3", "0", "0", "0\n"]["Amezcua", "2", "1", "2", "0", "2\n"]["Avalos", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0\n"]["\n"]
```

I am confused with what I get from the powershell output. Firstly my txt only contains three lines, why is it that powershell prints out 4 array instead of 3?. Secondly, why is that the element of every last array contains **\n**, I don't want that. Thirdly if I replaced print with puts, I wouldn't have the issue of **\n** on every last element of the arrays; why is that so?

To add on, I will explain the reason why I want to remove \n from the last element of the array. The numbers in txt document represents placing of an individual in a tournament whereby e.g. Acosta,1,3,0,0,0 means Acosta scored the first placed in the first match, third in the second match, and no placing in the remaining matches. Hence I want to assign a point system based on the placing each individual scored and finally printing out the total score of each person.

Therefore I used an ifelsif sequence to assign the score as follow

```
 file = open("score2.txt", "r")

 file.each do |line|
    array = line.split(",")
  name = array.shift
  score = 0
  array.each do |placing|
    if placing == "1"
      score += 6
    elsif placing == "2"
      score += 4
    elsif placing == "3"
      score += 2
    else
      score = score
    end
  end
  print "#{name}: #{score} "
end
```

However due to \n in the last element of an array, I am unable to assign points to the last match of the tournament. Hence I want to remove the \n from the last element of the arrays.

This exercise is from http://www.evc-cit.info/cit020/beginning-programming/chp_05/exercises2.html.

Can someone kindly enlighten me? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\n` represents a new line character.

- Your text file has a new (blank line) at the very end, so it actually has 4 lines.
- The last array in your return statement with `\n` represents the
  blank new line at the end of your text file.
- The last element in every array has a `\n` character because each array represents each of your lines in your text file. Each line is followed by a new line (represented by the `\n` character).
- In Ruby, `puts` adds a new line at the end of each argument, while `print` uses `\n` to represent a new line.

---

If you want to remove the `\n` from your output, you could simplify your code like this:

```rb
open("score2.txt", "r")

file.each do |line|
  print line.split
end
```

If you want to remove the `\n` from your output, but preserve new lines, you could use `p` instead of `print`:

```rb
open("score2.txt", "r")

file.each do |line|
  p line.split
end
```

If you want your output to look like what you have in your text file, you could use `puts`:

```rb
open("score2.txt", "r")

file.each do |line|
  puts line.split
end
```

---

This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018633/what-is-the-difference-between-print-and-puts) might be helpful, since it discusses the differences between `puts` and `print` in Ruby.

This [article](http://www.garethrees.co.uk/2013/05/04/p-vs-puts-vs-print-in-ruby/) explains the difference between `puts`, `print`, and `p` in Ruby.

**Update:**

To remove the `\n` new lines from your example, add `placing = placing.chomp` before your conditionals.

You can also use the bang `!` operator with `chomp` to modify the `placing` string in place i.e. `chomp!`:

```rb
file = open("score2.txt", "r")

file.each do |line|
  array = line.split(",")
  name = array.shift
  score = 0
  array.each do |placing|
    placing.chomp!
    if placing == "1"
      score += 6
    elsif placing == "2"
      score += 4
    elsif placing == "3"
      score += 2
    else
      score = score
    end
  end
  print "#{name}: #{score} "
end
```

Comment: Hi how do I remove the \n from the last element of the array?

Comment: Hi :) I Updated my answer

Comment: Hi, I think I am unclear in my question, could you kindly read my qns agn?

Comment: Sorry. I see what you intended. If you add `placing = placing.chomp` on the line before your first `if` statement, you can eliminate line breaks - more about [chomp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp)

Answer (score 3):

You want `line.chomp.split(',')`.

`chomp` removes a newline from the end of a string.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of methods available to remove `\n` like `chomp`,`strip`

Try following code:

```
file = open("score2.txt", "r")

file.each do |line|
  array = line.chomp.split(",")
  array1 = line.strip.split(",")
  print array
  print array1
end
```